# What is the largest volume CakePHP site out there?

Tags: php, cakephp

What is the largest website out there using the CakePHP framework?

I'm interested in pageview volume mostly, so I will use Alexa Traffic Rank and Reach metrics to evaluate the answers.

Comment: How is this not programming related? If I was deciding if I should use CakePHP, I might want to take a look at high-traffic CakePHP sites to see if CakePHP can handle the high volume...

Answer (score 1):

I know that the firefox addon pages were once done in cake.. not sure if they still are.

Also see [Sites in the Wild](http://book.cakephp.org/view/510/Sites-in-the-wild) from the cookbook.

Comment: It seems to still be done with cake ; see for instance https://wiki.mozilla.org/Update:Remora_Server_Requirements (AMO requirements include Cake's requirements)